# How to solve the integral $\int \frac{y}{\cos^2(y)}~dy$.

Tags: integration, derivatives, differential

I would like to compute the integral of

$$\int \frac{y}{\cos^2(y)}~dy.$$

Here is what I tried:

$$u=\cos(y),\quad du=-\sin(y)~dy,$$

$$dv=y~dy,\quad v=y^2/2,$$

$$uv-\int v~du=\frac{y^2}{2}\cos(y)+\int \frac{y^2}{2}\sin(y)~dy.$$

The expected answer is
$$y(\tan y)+\ln(\cos(y)).$$

How can I get to this? Thanks guys.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. First of all, one of the rules of this community mentions that you should include your own try. So, please write what you have already tried on solving the problem. Also, please consider checking this page on "how to use Mathjax": https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference .

Comment: Integration by parts.

Comment: Please write your question clearly and completely, preferably using MathJax. Thank you!

Comment: Hey guys , i didn't find my answer yet

Comment: I just converted what you wrote in your picture to MathJax, is this okay?

Comment: *Hint:* Instead of integrating $y$, try differentiating it instead (i.e. let $u=y$ and $dv=\frac{1}{\cos^2(y)}~dy$).

Comment: Thank you , I got that , by the way thanks for editing my question text , it helps me to write my next questions more correct and better :)

Answer (score 1):

Use integration by parts using
$$u=y \qquad du=dy$$
$$dv=\frac {dy}{\cos^2(y)}\implies v=\tan(y)$$ as a result
$$y\tan(y)-\int \tan(y) \,dy=y\tan(y)-\int \frac {\sin(y)}{\cos(y)} \,dy$$ which looks simple.

Comment: Thank you :) , it was helpful and i found my problem in solution .

Answer (score 0):

Since you are taking "u= cos(y) dv= ydy"m=,you appear to be using integration by parts to integrate $\int cos(y) ydy$ rather than $\int \frac{y}{cos^2(y)} dy$.